# json object with array of arrays

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am trying to create two polygons on a google map using the google map API.

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: -94.963194,39.316858,-94.95967,39.32199,-94.95905,39.32172,-94.95846,39.3214,-94.95792,39.32104,-94.95742,39.32064,-94.95698,39.32021,-94.95625,39.31927,-94.95599,39.31876,-94.95578,39.31824,-94.95564,39.3177,-94.95557,39.31716,-94.95557,39.31661,-94.963194,39.316858

I hope someone can help explain what I am doing wrong and kindly offer a resolution.

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
</script>
<script>
var map;

function initialize() {
    var kansas_city = new google.maps.LatLng(39.00495613,-94.64780668);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: kansas_city,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'sector.json';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

  // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
  // set of coordinates.
  window.sector_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      alert(coords);
      var polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: coords,
      map: map
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

JSON code:

```
sector_callback({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "1_1",
            "Description": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-94.963194, 39.316858],
                    [-94.959670, 39.321990],
                    [-94.959050, 39.321720],
                    [-94.958460, 39.321400],
                    [-94.957920, 39.321040],
                    [-94.957420, 39.320640],
                    [-94.956980, 39.320210],
                    [-94.956250, 39.319270],
                    [-94.955990, 39.318760],
                    [-94.955780, 39.318240],
                    [-94.955640, 39.317700],
                    [-94.955570, 39.317160],
                    [-94.955570, 39.316610],
                    [-94.963194, 39.316858]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "214_1",
            "Description": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-94.783917, 39.083417],
                    [-94.776470, 39.084670],
                    [-94.776340, 39.084140],
                    [-94.776290, 39.083590],
                    [-94.776300, 39.083040],
                    [-94.776380, 39.082500],
                    [-94.776530, 39.081960],
                    [-94.777020, 39.080940],
                    [-94.777360, 39.080460],
                    [-94.777760, 39.080000],
                    [-94.778210, 39.079570],
                    [-94.778710, 39.079180],
                    [-94.779260, 39.078830],
                    [-94.783917, 39.083417]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon array is an array of arrays (to support multiple paths in the polygon).
To access the numbers you need to do (assuming you have simple polygons with a single path):

```
var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
```

then convert them to google.maps.LatLng objects:

```
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]));
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygonsFromJson.html)

Answer (score 1):

Array looping in JS should never be done the default way. The browser will look for results.features.length at every step of the iteration. This is for speed considerations.

```
window.sector_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0, j = results.features.length; i < j; i++) {
      var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      alert(coords);
      var polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: coords,
      map: map
      });
  }
}
```

For the answer, check out **[THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295068/google-maps-v3-invalid-value-for-constructor-parameter-0-while-drawing-polyline)**

Comment: Never say never, if you are looping though an array and adding items while you loop, you *have* to check the length for each iteration. Besides, in modern browsers there is such a small difference between a variable lookup and a property lookup that you rarely need to do anything other than the default way.

Comment: No, it should not be done like you describe for any iteration where it is possible. What you are doing is called micro-optimising. You should start with the simplest implementation, and optimise it if needed.

Comment: That's pretty harmless as long as it's not contagious. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the Google Maps API requires using google's `google.maps.LatLng`-based data structures. Since the values in your JSON-data are `[longitude, latitude]`, you'll need to build `google.maps.LatLng` objects out of them before creating your polygon:

```
window.sector_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0, len = results.features.length; i < len; i++) {
    var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
    var path = [];

    for ( var j = 0, len2 = coords.length; j < len2; j++ ){
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]));
    }

    var polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: path,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

Edit: I had to specify the `0th` element for the coordinates, oops!

Comment: Hello Jason - Your solution seems to be getting all the lat/longs correctly from the geoJSON data but for some reason I am not seeing the polygons on the map. I am not seeing any compilation errors with firebug. Is there anything else I may have missed?